# WebView ignore Javascript that invokes PUT/DELETE Http method

Tags: javascript, android, http, webview, http-put

I have a web view that in it's HTML/Javascript makes an Http call with Put/Delete methods. those calls seems to be ignored (I test them on chrome and they work fine).

Any idea?

Here's the JS code that inside the WebView:

```
var req = new Backbone.Model(auth);

$.ajax({
            type: PUT,
            url: 'some_url',
            data: JSON.stringify(req)
        });
```

Note that this is an Ajax call from a jQuery.

Comment: I just tested on ICS emulator and it works there. why is it not working on earlier versions?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the `WebView` ignored the call is because of caching. It seems that the `PUT/DELETE` calls are cached.

Here's what I did to solve this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: methode,
    url: 'some_url?d' + new Date().getTime(),
    data: JSON.stringify(req),
});
```

As you can see I added a new `Date()` object creation in order to overcome that caching mechanism.

Thanks to Guy for helping out. You should definitely check out his blog at http://blog.guya.net/

Comment: is there any property to turn off caching?

Comment: Yes, WebView has several caching modes to choose from. check out WebSettings class at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```